# How to draw vertical lines based on a different quantity than that for the x channel in charts by row channel?

Tags: vega-lite

I'd like to have multiple time series drawn by row channel (`"field": "PLATFORM"`), x channel: (`"field": "estimating-date-time"`), and y channel (`"field": "eta-variance"`).
Besides the lines of time series, I'd like to draw a vertical line at `x = arrvial-time` which is another field, conditioned by the value of "PLATFORM".
The following is a working example of the charts except the desirable vertical line in each chart:
[vega-lite for multiple time series](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/5b3bd252c4dc7124c1a33154845b59c1/time-series.json)

Below is the desired effect with manual illustration:
[image: the desired effect with manual illustration]

My question is how to add the vertical line for each chart to the specifications?

The challenge to me is that the field "`arrival-time`" from which the value used to draw the vertical line is not the same as the chart's x channel "`estimating-data-time`". I've found examples of drawing such a line using a value related to the same x channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by nesting a [layer specification](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/layer.html) within a [facet operator](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/facet.html#facet-operator); something like this ([open in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgZghgxgpgLiAXKATgewO5NGAljAGwBMkQAFAGQEEAVAMQHkAlAWRAF92AaEAZwAcYUbCAAWMXAHNRCRAA4ADDwy4icUUgDMCpSAIQAnjBRIA2qAC2EFAGtSBXADsYIHjEdQ0RJ5JEAPETxCEkQQGF44XCtIx0kAWiIIOBg4yIsXHjgDQVJki340FAgCDh4DQPxiUgBRGio4gDdrXAgPDJAsnNCARwBXVsi4JNwGl05uS2s7UJRegnb3T29Y-wrg0msUEeLUqPbOl1C8gqKS8YBdbhBEoZEmgl7ws1Ba+qat1tgkAFYANh5NtsCLt0qQAEwKMEARjiCgA7HFNFCAATwxBQzSITQATlcYQiUWGsQSSRSaUOIAh0NhCKRqLhiAU2MQABYwXjKLRGKxSBQIXF2RMQK9Gs1Poc5HCASgtvcQRSqTD4YiUWiMVjcW4CdEfCTkvLwZClbTVQyoQp0eyeJz6Mw2KE+QoBaUXnVRR82kg4d9pbKduTDdTlXS1ZicXjwmkifEbmS9oHjSr6eiLWCWRzqLaeQ7+YKuK63mLPYhvizfUCDaFFTSk6GNRHtdG9XHQVWjTWQ2aLSz09bM9z7SBHc6hSL3i1i5p-iBAXKA22gybk+rw1qozEY6TK5T28HTeioYzNBmuXbebmXcK3ePxUgweW5-GF4nO+iw5r8evdbHt9W98vD00OETyzQdhzzAt3QnL5EDic0H39J8d0XWszXfBsv2JH952Ql99yhQ8WQ-G0B3PJ0IKvQsPRgsE5AQ4EcL-Jc61XT9CQ3Ztf13ZizTBA8QNInNyMvMcixgqFp1nRDW1wjt8PQtd2O-LdGO41DLUQMFjz7U9syHC9R2vMTDjg3QpIYpCmPUlcP0jJSsJUyy1NfKE+JZOQBLPISR3zSioNvWDvnvGcZQrVSUNfLTGQ8xSdQc-Vwrw5dmR0Ty9Ioc0fMgm9iziMsQr9CyZKsyLMQUGK2LizcEqciL8OZVy0rAzKKNE6iTO0eiuLq5MovKjD7OqlsFWc+qsWAnTQN5FqRKM9qkDib4oS6xK5N6sqKrsqrONW-81WZb5iP7LyhxmwyqOgkzfk0FbaqStE+s2xsOOwu61oei0CKa6bhPO-zcqA27itG9booG7bXuBnqPtZb5vodM7fLay6Fu+KUCrCt69oZR7wabSGRuhnHDwUOHJsE07fqRuaUdgqFsSBwn7pxja8ZexyoeZzTDzBCbyGO9LEey4yFpZG6McfTn3pZsHYvxjmmel7mSyheHKayvycpgxbGYTJXcbl9maql7HNL4jE1Yy37LnYIA)):

```json
{
  "facet": {"row": {"field": "PLATFORM"}},
  "spec": {
    "height": 80,
    "width": 300,
    "layer": [
      {
        "mark": "line",
        "encoding": {
          "x": {"field": "estimating-date-time", "type": "temporal"},
          "y": {"field": "ETA-variance", "type": "quantitative"}
        }
      },
      {
        "mark": "rule",
        "encoding": {"x": {"field": "arrival-time", "type": "temporal"}}
      }
    ]
  },
  "data": {...}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I want!